# VisualSVN Server: Is it possible to NOT inherit permission?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

**Currently behavior:**
There is a folder in our repository, called ImportantThings, normal users don't have access to.
From time to time new folders are added into ImportantThings, normal users don't have access to either.
After proving the new folder, access to a selected user amount is granted.

**Desired behavior:**
Similar to current, but normal user should have access to folder ImportantThings, so we don't have to share / checkout the new folders every time and the user just have to update / remember one folder.

**In one sentence:** Is it possible to NOT inherit rights, so a user has access to a folder, but not to folders children, except user got explicit rights to?

*A possible solution could be to create another folder and use externals there - but maybe somebody knows a more elegant way?*

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure if I get it right: You have a parent folder with several child folders and you want to give access to the parent folder but not the child folders (all of them)?

Comment: @royalTS correct. I want them to use SVN update on parent folder, but only get allowed children. And, in addition, if a new folder is created, it should be NOT access able.

Comment: In VisualSVN it is possible to configure the rights for each folder separately. This link should explain it: https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/. If you need additional information, update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Path Based Authorization??

One of the ways you can achieve this is using path based authorization in svn. 
A path based authorization allows you fine tune your access rights.

Say for example in your current behaviour:

```
reponame:/trunk/ImportantThings
# No user has access
```

This means that no user can read or right from this path. Meaning no folders and files can be read from ImportantThings.

Now say for example you need to give user1 and user2 read access.

What you will do is the following:

```
reponame:/trunk/ImportantThings/folder1/folder2/folder_to_give_access
user1 = r
user2 = r
reponame:/trunk/ImportantThings
# No user access
```

So what this will do that even though users 1 and 2 dont have access to ImportantThings entire folder. They can update and read from the folder_to_give_access folder which is actually inside the ImportantThings folder.

Comment: I'm, not sure I get you right, but in that case, no user has access to ImportantThings, and can't use svn update there, which is the core task of my issue. I wanna have a folder, where everybody has access, but if a new sub folder is created inside, nobody should have access per default. In other words: Do not inherit rights.

Comment: Well then you can reverse it
`reponame:/trunk/ImportantThings/folder1/folder2/folder_to_give_access
# No user access
reponame:/trunk/ImportantThings
user1 = r
user2 = r`
The base idea i am trying to convey is that each and every folder read and write rights can be configured by admin. It is only getting inherited as it is not explicitly mentioned by the svnadmin not to do that.

Comment: So just to be clear in your case folder creation is a two step process. The admin first creates the folder and then sets the rights using the path based authorization.